# How to disable old and new value option in output when I run PL/SQL program

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I am new to pl/sql so this might be a silly question, I created a simple PL/SQL program:

```
DECLARE
        inputData VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
        inputData :='&&inputData' ;
        Dbms_Output.put_line('Value entered is:' || inputData);
END;
/
```

When I run this program, I am getting below output:

```
Enter value for inputdata: check
old   4:         inputData :='&&inputData' ;
new   4:         inputData :='check' ;
Value entered is:check

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

How can we get rid of lines for old and new values when the output is displayed.

Comment: +1 Great question. Just what I was looking for. But What's the difference between a parameter with only one & and one with two & ? &inputData vs &&inputData.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

simply set this (see the [sqlplus user guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)):

```
set verify off
```

at the top of your script.

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> DECLARE
  2          inputData VARCHAR2(1024);
  3  BEGIN
  4          inputData :='&&inputData' ;
  5          Dbms_Output.put_line('Value entered is:' || inputData);
  6  END;
  7  /
Enter value for inputdata: sdf

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 5):

To disable :old and :new output use:

```
SET VERIFY OFF;
```

To disable update and other outputs:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
```

To fully disable all output:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF;
```